# ClassNotFoundException when downloaded from Google Play

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I've got a problem involving ClassNotFoundException. When i "Run as android application" from eclipse it works fine, but when i download it from Google Play (same source code but "Exported as signed app") it crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.larphoid.aeboing/com.larphoid.aeboing.BoingBoing}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.larphoid.aeboing.BoingBoing in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.larphoid.aeboing-1.apk]     
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2703)   
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)    
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)     
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)     
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)     
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)  
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)     
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.larphoid.aeboing.BoingBoing in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.larphoid.aeboing-1.apk]     
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)    
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)    
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)    
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1033)   
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)   
... 11 more
```

I've never had this problem before, and i'm not experienced yet in "reading" Stacktraces, so i'm pretty much puzzled at this. If anyone has some pointers or solution i'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: mark as answered, the hook right beneath the downvote button of the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gonna copy this from another question as I had the exact same problem before, and this is how I fixed it:

> If you're running adt rev 22, you might not be exporting your libraries. I don't know why 
>   Google did this exactly, but in the newest revolution you have to
>   check to make sure you're exporting your libraries yourself.
>
> Right click your project, click Properties, and check Order & Export
>   under Java Build Path. It should look like this if you want to export
>   everything:
>
> [image]
>   Afterwards, rebuild the application and export it again. It should be working now. To test, simply install the .apk to your phone manually before putting it on the store to  make sure it works.

Comment: whow thanks a million, I would never have found that ! if I could vote up a million i'd do that :)

Comment: No problem :) Please accept the answer if this ended up fixing your problem so others can find it easier.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassNotFoundException` indicates that something is missing on the classpath. Maybe you are missing a library in the classpath.

> As the name suggests classNotFoundException in Java is a subclass of java.lang.Exception and Comes when Java Virtual Machine tries to load a particular class and doesn't found the requested class in classpath.

Comment: downvote cuz not quite the complete answer for this. See answer Sander van't Veer for correct answer !

Comment: accept his answer instead of downvoting... Sander is adding libraries to the classpath, but with pictures.

Comment: sorry, didn't realize you were talking about the same thing. I'm not very familiar with the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you `change` your `package name` while signing your apk.
Check your `package` and `class name`